# utilizar ref em uma lista sem v-for vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Olá, tenho uma lista simples na qual não utilizo o v-for. Gostaria de saber se é possível identificar o item da lista através do #ref no vue.js;
Normalmente identifico meus componentes com name e Id, porém estou utilizando um componente de terceiros o qual não tenho acesso a essas propriedades. 
Preciso pegar o índice do item da lista e gostaria de saber como fazer isso pelo ref.

Grata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível.
Quando não utilizando o `v-for`, a `ref` se torna uma variável comum, podendo ser resgatada com `this.$refs.suaref`.

Utilizando o `ref` no componente com o `v-for` o nome dado na referência se 
torna uma array de componentes, utilizando `this.$refs.suaref[indice]` é possível trabalhar com o componente referenciado.

**Obs**:
Mesmo com componentes de terceiros é possível utilizar `id` e `name`(não o do .vue, o do componente mesmo) sobre eles, todas as propriedades podem ser utilizadas, e ela será adicionada no elemento raiz do componente, mas geralmente o `id` que você define sobrepõe o do componente, mas raramente quem faz um componente utiliza o `id`.